# Trouble creating grayscale image from array of pixel intensities with ImageMagick

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I'm trying to output a png grayscale image using values from an array of intensity values using ImageMagick.

I've used the Image constructor to try to do this, but the image it is creating does not exactly match the given array.

```
Image grayscaleImage(256, 256, "I", DoublePixel, inputPtr);
grayscaleImage.write("test.png");
```

The image that's being created has the correct values for all of the black pixels (intensity of 0) but for the non-zero pixels, I'm getting only white; no gray. How can I correct this issue? Or am I using the constructor incorrectly? Thank you!

Comment: How is `inputPtr` defined? Are the pixel values between `0.0` & `1.0` ?

Comment: inputPtr is a pointer to an array containing values from 0.0 to 255.0. Should I scale these values to be between 0.0 and 1.0?

Comment: Yes! For `Magick::DoublePixel`, you'll need to ensure each pixel value is a normalized double between `0.0` & `1.0`.

Comment: This solved the problem! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As emcconville stated, the numbers in the array of integers need to be scaled to be between `0.0` and `1.0` for `Magick::DoublePixel`. I achieved this by using the following function:

```
       (b-a)(x - min)
f(x) = --------------  + a
          max - min
```

Where `a == 0`, `b == 1`, `x == inputPtr[index]`, `min == 0`, and `max == 255`.